# ListView's row pressed color with gradient background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, listviewitem

I want to have rows with gradient background in my ListView and i want them to change to a solid color when pressed. But i can't get it right. 
I know about the problem ListViews have and i read some solutions in other topics but none of them seems to work for me. Any help would be great.

When i run the following code i get this image that is ok:
[image: Before pressed]

But when i press on item 2, all rows will be green!:
[image: after pressed]

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mMenuItems;

    StateListDrawable mBackgroundDrawable;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;

        mMenuItems= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mMenuItems.add(String.format("Item %d", i));
        }

        // make background drawable
        GradientDrawable backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[]{  Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED});
        backgroundDrawable.setCornerRadius(0f);

        ColorDrawable selectedColorDrawable= new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN);

        mBackgroundDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        mBackgroundDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, selectedColorDrawable);
        mBackgroundDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, selectedColorDrawable);
        mBackgroundDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected}, selectedColorDrawable);
        mBackgroundDrawable.addState(new int[] {}, backgroundDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMenuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mMenuItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewGroup item = getViewGroup(convertView);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            item.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
        } else {
            item.setBackground(mBackgroundDrawable);
        }
        // set title
        TextView titleView= (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.menu_title);
        titleView.setText(mMenuItems.get(position));
        return item;
    }

    public ViewGroup getViewGroup(View reuse)
    {
        if(reuse instanceof ViewGroup)
            return (ViewGroup)reuse;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_menu, null);

        return item;
    }
}
```

My row_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity's layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_listview);
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mBackgroundDrawable is common for all your Rows. You need to attach a unique mBackgroundDrawable to every row (for example inside your loop where you add it). This is pretty much straightforward, but feel free to ask if you need a specific example ! ;)

Comment: Yes, i know it's common. But it's not a single color, it's a statedrawable! and two rows can't be pressed in the same time.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. But why does it matter? Why should i use a separate statelistdrawable for each row?

Comment: @Mbt925 Well, every row you had got its color from the same `mBackgroundDrawable`. So if you change the color of the `mBackgroundDrawable` and as every row has the same reference, they will all have the same color. It's like having 10 chameleons in front of one unique big wall. If you repaint your big wall, every chameleon will change their color. But if you "create" a "small" wall for every chameleon you have (and change the color of the desired wall), only one chameleon will change color. :)

Comment: I didn't see it that way! I was thinking graphically not programmatically!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it through the XML it self.

ListView

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

drawables/list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

drawables/list_item_bg_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

drawables/list_item_bg_normal.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

As you can see the ListView has an attr named  android:listSelector and it's value is "@drawable/list_selector". This is where we setting the selector.
and i think the rest is Self Explanatory.

If you need more clarification, read this http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial

Comment: I know about listSelector, but i have to do it programmatically.

Comment: Another thing is, in your approach, normal background color will not apply to all rows, just the row currently selected